# How do I connect to Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I want to switch over from mySQL to Neo4j for my website. 
With mySQL, the code would be something like 
  `$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);`
But what's the code for Neo4j?

Answer (score 1):

In Python for example it looks like this:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4j_uri, auth=(neo4j_username, neo4j_password))
```

Check the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/client-applications/) for more information.